# Software Center got removed by uninstalling Perl

Tags: software-center, perl

I tried to uninstall Perl from my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS by the command-

```
sudo apt-get remove --auto-remove perl
```

Due to this command Software Center app is removed and won't reinstall by install software-center command.

Comment: Are you sure about this? Software center has NO dependencies on perl ... it is made in python and depends on python. Plus: are you sure you have software-center and not gnome-software? 18.04 should not have software-center.That was 16.04: https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=software-center&searchon=names

Comment: @Rinzwind either way, removing perl will break all sorts of things. It is a very, very basic package. Mohit, can you reinstall perl? You really, *really* don't want to remove it.